# checking data format with a function instead of multiple preg_matches

Tags: php

I'm trying to check the data format of multiple variables, 21 to be precise, with a function instead of using a preg_match for every single variable as they are supposed to be dates, numeric, alphabetic, alphanumeric and not empty and I'm using the following function for multiple data check in a single row, the function seems to return false, is there anything wrong with them?Thanks for any help in advance, here's the code.

```
<?php
    function alphabetic_check(){
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        for($n = 0; $n < $numargs; $n++){
            $x = preg_match("^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", $arg_list[$n]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($n == $numargs - 1 && $x == true){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function numeric_check(){
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        for($n = 0; $n < $numargs; $n++){
            $x = preg_match("^[0-9]*$/", $arg_list[$n]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($n == $numargs - 1 && $x == true){
                return true;
            }
        }
    } 
    
    function alphanumeric_check(){
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        for($n = 0; $n < $numargs; $n++){
            $x = preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/", $arg_list[$n]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($n == $numargs - 1 && $x == true){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function not_empty(){
        $n = func_num_args();
        $args = func_get_args();
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
            $x = !empty($args[$i]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($i == $n - 1 && $x == true){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

and here's the code for kinda a reservation system I'm developing returning a promt saying that the data format is incorrect even if it is supposed to excecute the code inside the if block...

```
 if(numeric_check($id, $cellphone, $people, $single, $double, $twin, $superior, $suite, $triple, $quadruple, $disabled, $ccn, $ccm, $ccy, $cccvc) && alphabetic_check($fistname, $lastname, $type) && not_empty($id, $user, $firstname, $lastname, $cellphone, $arrival, $departure, $people, $ccn, $ccm, $ccy, $cccvc, $type)){
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        mysqli_close($connection);
        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                window.alert('Data format wrong, retry.');
                window.location.replace('control_panel.php');
            </script>
        ";
    }
```

This is the handwritten code that actually works but I was wondering how to squeeze this stuff as above:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $id) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*$/", $user) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", $firstname) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", $lastname) && preg_match("/^[\+0-9]{10,}$/", $cellphone) && preg_match("/^[0-9\-]*$/", $arrival) && preg_match("/^[0-9\-]*$/", $departure) && preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $people) && $people > 0 && preg_match("/^[0-9]{16}$/", $ccn) && preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}$/", $ccm) && preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}$/", $ccy) && preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}$/", $cccvc) && preg_match("/^[a-z]*$/", $type) && !empty($id) && !empty($user) && !empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($cellphone) && !empty($arrival) && !empty($departure) && !empty($people) && !empty($ccn) && !empty($ccm) && !empty($ccy) && !empty($cccvc) && !empty($type)){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    mysqli_close($connection);
    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            window.alert('Formato dati errato, riprova.');
            window.location.replace('pannello.php');
        </script>
    ";
}
```

**Question solved by Mark, here below the working code with some tests:**

```
<?php
    function alphabetic_check(){
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        for($n = 0; $n < $numargs; $n++){
            $x = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", $arg_list[$n]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($n == $numargs - 1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function numeric_check(){
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        for($n = 0; $n < $numargs; $n++){
            $x = preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $arg_list[$n]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($n == $numargs - 1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    } 
    
    function alphanumeric_check(){
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        for($n = 0; $n < $numargs; $n++){
            $x = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/", $arg_list[$n]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($n == $numargs - 1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function not_empty(){
        $n = func_num_args();
        $args = func_get_args();
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
            $x = !empty($args[$i]);
            if($x == false){
                return false;
            } else if($i == $n - 1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    $a = "voda";
    $b = 17;
    $c = "coding101";
    $d = NULL;
    
    echo "Alphabetic check: " . (alphabetic_check($a, $b, $c) ? "true" : "false") . "<br /><br />"; 
    echo "Alphanumeric check: " . (alphanumeric_check($a, $b, $c) ? "true" : "false") . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Numeric check: " . (numeric_check($a, $b, $c) ? "true" : "false") . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Not empty: " . (not_empty($a, $b, $c) ? "true" : "false") . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Not empty 2: " . (not_empty($a, $b, $c, $d) ? "true" : "false") . "<br /><br />";
?>
```

Comment: Sir I apologize but I think you don't understand the code, only if the last preg_match of the last argument is true then the function returns true and returns false even if only one value doesn't satisfy the preg match formula, how would you perform such task?

Comment: I understand what your code does, but apparently you don’t. _“and returns false even if only one value doesn't satisfy”_ - yes, because that’s what return does - it exits the function right there and then. So if you `return false` on the first non-successful test, then your loop will not continue, all further items will not be checked any more.

Comment: If you want a result of `true` only if _all_ test pass, then you can return false after the first false one - but with returning `true`, you need to wait until you checked _all_ items.

Comment: Exactly Sir all further items will not be checked that's for preventing potential SQL injections, if you see the code from line 9 to 11 you will see...

Comment: Rejecting data because it does not pass some sort of validation, and preventing SQL injection, are two completely different things to begin with.

Comment: Sir can you please explain us how a hacker could potentially inject some SQL code with the preg_match functions?This is data format validation, data can also be false but at least the format is right...

Comment: @der_Loewen Have you considered using filter_var_array()?

Comment: I used it for emails, in this case I'd like to understand what's wrong with the code, I have the reservation system up and working but without the "..._check" functions maybe using multiple arguments inside a function could be useful as I have to validate a lot of data all the time... thank you Sir.

Comment: _“how a hacker could potentially inject some SQL code with the preg_match functions?”_ - I did not say that; I said that validation, and prevention of SQL injection, are two very different things to begin with, so don’t confuse one for the other. What you are limiting the potential values to here, _might_ have the side effect of eliminating SQL injection possiblities as well, here in this case. But that does not mean, that the two are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems:

1. None of your preg_matches have an opening delimeter, e.g. you have: `preg_match("^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"`, this is missing a forward slash at the start, should be: `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"`. This applies to all preg_matches so a error is thrown.
2. You have an incorrectly named variable, you have `alphabetic_check($fistname,` , should be `$firstname` as used elsewhere

Fixing those 2 and plugging in some valid data and your functions work fine.

May I suggest a slight change to the functions though that may make them easier toread, for example:

```
function alphabetic_check(){
  $arg_list = func_get_args();
  $valid = true;
  foreach($arg_list as $arg){
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", $arg))
    {
      $valid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return $valid;
}
```

With my version we set a variable, $valid, to be true. If any of the preg_matches fail then we set valid to false and break out the loop. This way there is no need to check if you are on the last arg in the list. As a result you can also change to a foreach loop and no need to count the number of arguments passed in.

Comment: thank you for your answer unfortunately I do a lot of typos, I will find a way to fix this, have a nice day, I'll leave the working code with some examples.